# Firebase snapshotchanges retrieve data

Tags: firebase, angularfire2

I'm trying to retrieve Firebase data ( Angularfire2 ) with the snapshotchanges observable. I was doing that ok with valuechanges but in this case the object keys are not retrieved.

But with snapshotchanges I got an array of "payload' objects. Until I know I need to use a map function in this case but the map function is not accepted for snapshotchanges.

Any thoughts on how to iterate on the retrieved objects in this case please ?

Comment: Here is one example how I do it:         let dataBaseCollection = this.store.collection('lists').snapshotChanges().pipe(
            map(actions =>
                actions.map(a => ({ key: a.payload.doc.id, data: a.payload.doc.data() })
                )
            ));

Comment: Hi, tryied :   let dataBaseCollection = db.list('lists').snapshotChanges().pipe( map(actions => actions.map(a => ({ key: a.payload.doc.id, data: a.payload.doc.data() }) ) ) ....but map is not recognized.

Comment: Which rxjs version you are using? and consider if you are using angular fire 2 you need the rxjs version of 6

Comment: Hi @Benjamim Shröder, you're correct. It's working after install latest rxjs version. Thank you very much !

Comment: I just added it as answer to close this thread down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to close this down. I provided the comment to update the RXJS version to 6. Its a very similar problem to many other RXJS version problems.

Be careful and see into the migration guide to update your rxjs version from 5 to 6 Link: [Migration guide for RXJS](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md)

Comment: I did all that was mentioned above, except that I have the following error: `Property 'doc' does not exist on type 'DatabaseSnapshot<unknown>'.` which is related to the `doc` part of `a.payload.doc.id`, etc. Do you know why I might be getting this error?